# Can't solve CSS sprites issue

Tags: html, css, browser, sprite

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, to me the code seems right but I guess it's not or else it would be working. The actual sprite button isn't showing up in the browser, I can click on the invisible button but I'm unable to see it, and I have no idea how to fix it. Help is needed.

**Here's the CSS**

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
a.button
{
    height: 48px;
    background-image: url("images/Home.png");
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#home
{
    width: 186px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}

#home:hover
{
    background-position: 0px -40px;
}

#home:active
{
    background-position: 0px -80px;
}
```

**Here's the HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>

<body>
<a href="#" class="button" id="home">Home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a link to this?

Comment: No I don't have a link

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code. However, you don't really need the `text-indent: -9999px;` ..Just don't put any text in it.

It must be your image location `"images/Home.png"` must not be the right path.

Take a look at what happens when I switch the image: http://jsfiddle.net/KAHwf/

Comment: Now the question is why is it having trouble with my path? that path works in the HTML markup but not is CSS

Comment: Is your CSS in the same location as your page?

Comment: Yup, everything is in the same location.

Comment: Is that including the picture? or is it in the images folder?

Comment: Picture is in the images folder.